# Play android Recorded file into PC

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, android-sdk-2.1

I am using below code to record voice.

But, when I play that recorded file in pc. No music player can play. while in phone it's playing very well.

Dose anybody can say that how can i play android recorded file in desktop or laptop.

Code that I am using.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.app.Activity;

import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;


public class AudioRecorder extends Activity {
     AudioRecorder ar;
    String FILENAME="/compare1.wav";
    final MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
   String path;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        try{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Log.d("GPS","kartik");
        LinearLayout layout=new LinearLayout(this);
        Button btnStart = new Button(this);
        Button btnStop=new Button(this);

        btnStart.setText("START");
        btnStop.setText("STOP");

        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {

                    GetPath(FILENAME);

                    start();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });



        btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    stop();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        layout.addView(btnStart);
        layout.addView(btnStop);
        setContentView(layout);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    public String GetPath(String path) {
        return this.path = sanitizePath(path);
      }



    private String sanitizePath(String path) {
      if (!path.startsWith("/")) {
        path = "/" + path;
      }
      if (!path.contains(".")) {
        path += ".3gp";
      }
      return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + path;
    }


    /**
     * Starts a new recording.
     */
    public void start() throws IOException {
        try{
      String state = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState();
      if(!state.equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))  {
          throw new IOException("SD Card is not mounted.  It is " + state + ".");
      }

      // make sure the directory we plan to store the recording in exists
      File directory = new File(path).getParentFile();
      if (!directory.exists() && !directory.mkdirs()) {
        throw new IOException("Path to file could not be created.");
      }

      recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
      recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
      recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
      recorder.setOutputFile(path);
      recorder.prepare();
      recorder.start();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Stops a recording that has been previously started.
     */
    public void stop() throws IOException {
        try{
      recorder.stop();
      recorder.release();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

I think I see your problem in your code you told it to use 3gp Codec to record the audio

```
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
```

but you use the .wav extension this is going to make the computer think you used a different codec to record the file (wave codec) I do believe the phone is ignoring the file extension and instead checking the file metadata to get the actual codec used and that's why the phone can play it.

So either you have to change the output format to use wave instead or a better Idea (since even short sound clips in wave format have huge file size) would be to change the file extension to 3gp so this will help

```
String FILENAME="/compare1.3gp";
```

now if you don't have a media player that can playback that format you'll have to get one, I do believe VLC player can do it and that's a free program

now for a more detailed description of what's going on:
Codecs are like a language in that it's a set of rules defining what symbols and patterns are used to represent the sound, just like a language uses words and patterns of words (like a sentence or paragraph) to convey what a person is trying to say.
so to make an analogy,

your phone writes the sound file in English an then says on the cover this book is written in Greek. now you give the file to the computer. The computer knows Greek and that's what the cover says to use and so goes to read thought it as if it where, but since Greek and English are not at all similar when written out. all it sees is what looks like gibberish, it doesn't make the connection the file may be in a different language it goes strictly by what's on the cover and what it found isn't Greek so it can't read it.  Your Phone on the other hand looks at the information about the file and in there it can see the author was using English when they wrote it so the phone goes to read the file as if it was in English and since it was the contents make perfect sense to the phone and vola it was able to play the music because it could understand the instructions on how to reproduce the music.

Answer (score 0):

What is your output filename .. something like `compare1.wav.3gp` ? Rename it to compare.3gp

Also what are you using on the PC? VLC should be able to play your file. I don't think it this problem is related to Android's recording, rather it may be a PC-not-being-able-to-play-3gp kind of a problem

Answer (score 0):

I use code from Android guide and I had the same problem.
I've solved this via using another audio encoder:

```
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
```

Hope this help.